# External log with spring boot from an application.yml

Tags: spring-boot, logback

I would like have an external log of my application, but I haven't managed to do it. I have the logaback.xml in resources folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
  <logger name="org.springframework.web" level="DEBUG"/>
</configuration>
```

And I have an application.yml with this content:

```
    # ========================    
    # LOGGING    
    # ========================

 #logging:
 file: /tmp/application.log
 # Enable this to specify the path and the name of the log file. By default, it creates a
 # file named spring.log in the temp directory.
```

In the folder tmp the only one file is spring.log, with all logs from the application, but I need a file with other name and with a level  debug in a different folder.

Anybody can help me?

Thank you!

Comment: I have just resolve it. The problem was I had forgotten delete the character #.